# pdf in browser - how to view list of search results

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, pdf, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

I used to be able to search a PDF and view a list of the search results inside the browser using Adobe's plugin.

However, with the change in browser plugin architecture it appears Adobe's PDF plugin no longer works like before.

Is there a plugin on ANY browser that accomplishes this?

If possible, provide a list for each browser.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome and Firefox both have default embedded own plugins for PDF which support searching the doc contents and render results inside the browser window.

Comment: LIST of search results